# How to Export Functions from Mongoose Model and Use it in a Controller in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create certain functions in my mongoose models and export them and then use them in my controllers.

But when i try to export and use that function in my controller it just tells me that it is not a function.

For instance i am trying to create a register function in my User model and use it in my controller, but it is throwing an error

```
"TypeError: User.register is not a function
"
```

What am i doing wrong?

Here is my code:

User.js:

```
const usersSchema = new Schema({

  name: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  verified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
})

exports.register = async (studentID, name, username, email, password, verified ) => {

  const exists = await this.find({ email })

  if(exists) {
    throw Error("User Already Exists")
  }

  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
  const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)

  let userDocument = {
    name: name,
    username: username,
    email: email,
    password: hash,
    verified: verified
  }

  const user = await this.insertOne(userDocument)

  return user
}
```

UsersController.js:

```
const User = require('../models/User')

router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {

    const { studentID, name, username, email, password, verified } = req.body

    User.register(req.body).then((response) => {
        if(response) {
            res.json({
                msg:"registered"
            })
        } else {
            res.json({
                msg:"failed"
            })
        }
    })

  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use -> "`module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)`" at end of you model's file in order to use your "users" in other controller functions.

Below I've tweaked your code a little bit.

user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const usersSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  verified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

usersController.js:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const User = require('../models/user');

router.post('/register', async (req, res, next) => {

    const { studentID, name, username, email, password, verified } = req.body;

    try {
        const exists = await User.findOne({ email: email });

        if (exists) {
            throw Error("User Already Exists");
        }

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        let userDocument = {
            name: name,
            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: hash,
            verified: verified
        }

        const user = new User(userDocument);  // instead of insertOne, create an new object of that model and use .save() method to save the data in collection.
        const result = await user.save();

        res.status(201).json({
            msg: "registered"
        });

    } catch (err) {
        const error = new Error(err);
        error.httpStatusCode = 500;
        return next(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: I know that it will work this way, i tried it, what i want to do is create functions in my models file and then use them in the controller. How can i do that?